# Getting Null Exception in GooglePlus Page API

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I got an exception frequently while getting and posting activities via GooglePlus Page API. The details are given below:

APIs:
https://www.googleapis.com/plusPages/v2/people/userId/activities/collection

https://www.googleapis.com/plusPages/v2/people/userId/activities

Exception:
{"error":{"message":null,"code":500}}

Can anyone tell me why i am getting the above exception and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I like to call 500 a server hiccup.  Normally you can just send the request again and it will work.   Why you are getting it only Google knows.  Just send it again.

> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500)
>
> Error code    Description
>  internalError   The request failed due to an
>   internal error.

You can find it in Googles [standard error responses](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/standard-error-responses?hl=en) page.